# Chart.js 2.7.2- Multiline get point value onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, momentjs

I would like to get value foreach point value.
Don't work because when I click on point I obtain only of the first line value.
GetElementsAtEvent give me an array of 3 element (element active) but how I can get the clicked value?

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/df6ecrg4/2/) the Complete code.

```
    $(document).on("click", "#canvas", function(event){
            var activePoints = ctx.getElementsAtEvent(event);
        if(activePoints.length > 0){

                var clickedDatasetIndex = activePoints[0]._datasetIndex;
                var clickedElementindex = activePoints[0]._index;
                var label = ctx.data.labels[clickedElementindex];
                var value = ctx.data.datasets[clickedDatasetIndex].data[clickedElementindex]["y"];  

                alert("Clicked: " + label + " - " + value);    
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the exact element, use `ctx.getElementAtEvent`.

```
$(document).on("click", "#canvas", function(event){
    var activePoint = ctx.getElementAtEvent(event);
        
    if (activePoint.length > 0) {
       var clickedDatasetIndex = activePoints[0]._datasetIndex;
       var clickedElementIndex = activePoints[0]._index;
       var clickedDatasetPoint = ctx.data.datasets[clickedDatasetIndex];
       var label = clickedDatasetPoint.label;
       var value = clickedDatasetPoint.data[clickedElementIndex]["y"];  

       alert("Clicked: " + label + " - " + value);    
    }
});
```